# How do I remove the last few characters in my table name?

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
    try:
        source_database=f'{source_database}.dbo'
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        read_table_query="""        
        SELECT table_name 
        FROM information_schema.tables
        ORDER BY table_name asc
            """
        cursor.execute(read_table_query)  

        logger.info("Successfully connected to database")

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Unable to connect to database: %s", str(e))    

    for tables in cursor.fetchall():
        tab = tables[0] 
        select_stg_query = f"""SELECT * from {tab}"""      
        try:
            df_select=pd.read_sql(select_stg_query, conn, chunksize=10000)
            warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
        except Exception as e:
            logger.exception(e)
            continue  

        try:
            engine = sa.create_engine(f'mssql+pyodbc://@{target_server}/{target_database}?trusted_connection=yes&driver={target_driver}')
            # cnxn = engine.connect()
            # truncate_query = sa.text(f"TRUNCATE TABLE {target_database}.dbo.{tab}")
            # cnxn.execution_options(autocommit=True).execute(truncate_query)
            # print(truncate_query)
            # cnxn.commit()

            for chunk_dataframe in df_select:
                rowcount = chunk_dataframe.to_sql(f'{tab}_BIC', engine, if_exists='append', index=False, method='multi', chunksize=10)
                warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
                print("{} Records inserted ".format(rowcount) + f"into {tab}")
                engine.dispose()

        except Exception as e:
            logging.exception(e)
```

The code is selecting all the tables in my STG database that all have the prefix 'stg_'. I want to select those tables but when I write data to those tables in the DW database, I want to remove the 'stg_' prefix. So when the new tables have data being written to them, there is no 'stg_' prefix. How do I remove it? I tried using:

`rowcount = chunk_dataframe.to_sql(f'{tab}_BIC'.strip('stg_'), engine, if_exists='append', index=False, method='multi', chunksize=10)`

but it still writes the 'stg_' part.

Comment: Thats not a sql server question - so I removed the tag